# Prevent showing Delete button if database table is empty?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I hide the delete button with this array if $count > 0. Is there a way inside the PHP code to do this? Can someone help? I'm also open for anyone who wants to revise the code to be more secure.

```
<form action="checkbox.php" method="post">

<?php
$query = "SELECT filmTitle, filmRole, filmDirector, idfilm FROM filmInfo, actorsInfo
WHERE (actorsInfo.id = filmInfo.id_actor) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_numrows($result);

if($count > 0){
echo "<table>";

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";   
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";   
echo "
    <td width='20' align='center'>#</td>
    <td width='200' align='center'>TITLE</td>
    <td width='200' align='center'>ROLE</td>
    <td width='200' align='center'>DIRECTOR</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";

$row_number = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $id_actor= $row["id_actor"];
  $idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
  $filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
  $filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
  $filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


  echo"<tr>";
  echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" value="'.$idfilm.'" type="checkbox" 
    id="checkbox'.$row_number.'" /></td>';


  for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)  {
   echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";
  }
  echo"</tr>";

  $row_number++;
  }
  echo"</table>";
  }

  ?>

  <input type="submit" name="deletefilm" value="Delete" />
  </form>
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: @DanielA.White - It's not really, $_SESSION is populated on the server so unless it's being assigned something malicious there... A bigger concern is the use of deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($count > 0){

    echo "<table>";

    echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";   
    echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";   
    echo    "

    <td width='20' align='center'>#</td>

    <td width='200' align='center'>TITLE</td>
    <td width='200' align='center'>ROLE</td>
    <td width='200' align='center'>DIRECTOR</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";

    $row_number = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id_actor= $row["id_actor"];
    $idfilm= $row["idfilm"]; 
    $filmTitle= $row["filmTitle"];
    $filmRole= $row["filmRole"];
    $filmDirector= $row["filmDirector"];


    echo"<tr>";
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" value="'.$idfilm.'" type="checkbox" 
    id="checkbox'.$row_number.'" /></td>';


    for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)  {
       echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";

    $row_number++;
    }
    echo"</table>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  My future goal is to secure the database that people keep warning me about. Not sure how to go about it other then reading up on the subject.